# Optimize table by removing large field

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a MySQL table of articles. It's growing rapidly, and over 50% of the size on disk is accounted for by the article body field, as you might expect. There are no indexes on the body, but 8/16 fields on the table are indexed.

My question is: going forward, will it be more efficient if I move the article body into a separate table? Will I gain more than I lose by forcing extra joins? Average body length is 3.3 kB and maximum length is 414 kB.

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `site_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `trend_id` CHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_added` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_scraped` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_published` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_shared` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `language` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `reach` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `title` TINYTEXT NULL,
    `summary` TEXT NULL,
    `keywords` TEXT NULL,
    `thumbnail` TEXT NULL,
    `body` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `url` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `status` ENUM('published','pending','disabled') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'published',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `site_id` (`site_id`),
    INDEX `date_published` (`date_published`),
    INDEX `language` (`language`),
    INDEX `reach` (`reach`),
    INDEX `trend_id` (`trend_id`),
    INDEX `date_added` (`date_added`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: how often do you need the body in your query?

Comment: Probably about 50% by volume uses either body or a brief excerpt, which could certainly be stored separately. As a matter of practice, I never `SELECT *` – even if I'm using every field, I always name them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITION` is unlikely to help.

`CHAR(32)` -- is it utf8?  If so, then it is taking 96 bytes; what a waste.  And it is hex, correct?  Consider converting to binary and using `BINARY(16)` to save space.  Note that (in InnoDB) the `PRIMARY KEY` is included in each secondary key.  So, 8 indexes times (96-16) bytes = 640 bytes per row saved.

In MySQL there are `HEX()` and `UNHEX()`.  Your programming language probabls has something.

Yes, do consider "vertical partitioning" to move the body to another table (body + id; primary key is id):

- Searching in the main table will be faster because of not tripping over the bodies.
- The `JOIN` to get the body won't be bad, especially since you won't be fetching many bodies at once.
- Consider making the `body` a `MEDIUMBLOB` and compressing (in the client) the text.  This will give you a big savings in disk space.  (And it is the only significant saving.)  Text typically compresses 3:1.

Make a decision soon.  Any change is likely to need both the old copy of the bodies and the new during the conversion.  The 50% is scary.

If you have 8 indexes, are any of them "composite"?  Are any just on a flag?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I've added the full create table as requested. You're correct about the encoding - I used `CHAR` instead of `BINARY` to make it easier to browse with command line/GUI clients, thinking that it was costing me 16 bytes per record by saving the hex rather than the binary form of the hash. Given what you say about encoding and keys, I'll definitely look into changing the data type.

Comment: `CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii` -- gives you the both smaller footprint (32 bytes) and GUI compatibility.

Comment: That reduced the overall size by 0.17% after running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. I guess every little bit helps, but it's not exactly overwhelming. I didn't do before/after benchmarks, though.

Comment: I discovered that HeidiSQL displays `BINARY` types in hex, so there's no downside. I've converted all of my hash keys to `BINARY(16)`, and my index size has reduced dramatically. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Unless `body` is a part of the primary key (which I doubt) it won't add more overheard.

50% of indexed fields is more a concern to me. I'd check if they all are used (see userstats in Percona Server) and if any of them are redundant (pt-duplicate-key-checker).

Comment: No, the primary key is a `CHAR(32)` hash. The index creep is a concern to me as well, but all of the indexes are being used in either `WHERE` (eg. language, trend_id) or `ORDER BY` (eg. date_published, popularity). I've been considering partitioning by language, though.

Comment: If the indexed filed shows up in a where clause that doesn't mean MySQL will use it